# select child who has a parent from the same table Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I have person table all father and mother in the same table of child

```
Pen-id     firstname  lastname gender  father-id mother-id
10002       Ti         Si-dao   M       null    null
10025       Leonardo    Vogel   M       10002   10010
10010       Marissa     Wilkes  F       null    null
```

I need view to show the following sentence

Ti is the father of Leonardo Vogel
Marissa  is the mother of Leonardo Vogel

I used the DDL but it did not work

```
CREATE VIEW parent AS
    SELECT (FIRSTNAME) ||' '|| (LASTNAME)|| (CASE WHEN GENDER ='F' THEN ' is the mother of'  ELSE 'is the father of' END) ||' '|| (FIRSTNAME) ||' '|| (LASTNAME)  AS PARENTAGE
    FROM P_PERSON ;
```

Comment: Why on earth do you need such a way of storing data in one single table?

Answer (score 1):

This Query will give you output as required But consider the below note also.

```
    select t2.firstname || ' Is Father Of '|| t1.firstname ||' '||t1.lastname 
    ||' , '||t3.firstname ||' Is Mother Of ' ||t1.firstname ||' '||t1.lastname as PARENTAGE
 from  P_PERSON  t1 , P_PERSON  t2 , P_PERSON  t3 where t1.father_id is not NULL 
    and t1.mother_id is not NULL and t1.father_id=t2.pen_id and t1.mother_id=t3.pen_id;
```

Check Here [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/18e85d/1/0)

> Note : Above table is an example of **Bad-Database design**. Ideally Your
>   Database should be in 3NF to achieve maximum performance. If possible
>   revise database design. Here make `Child` and `Parent` as different
>   objects / Tables to reduce headache.

**UPDATE**

To have output on separate line you can use `union`

```
        select t2.firstname || ' Is Father Of '|| t1.firstname ||' '||t1.lastname 
        as PARENTAGE from P_PERSON  t1 , P_PERSON  t2  
        where t1.father_id is not NULL and t1.father_id=t2.pen_id 
        union
        select t3.firstname ||' Is Mother Of ' ||t1.firstname ||' '||t1.lastname as 
        PARENTAGE from P_PERSON  t1 ,  P_PERSON  t3 where  t1.mother_id is not NULL and 
        t1.mother_id=t3.pen_id;
```

Check Here [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/18e85d/19)